# How to make proper PUT REQUEST to my API? JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 40

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I will try to briefly explain what happen. I tried to PUT some data into my API Gateway

```
 PUT myarn/prod/users
```

It doesn't work.

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

I looked at Cloudwatch

```
[ERROR] JSONDecodeError: Invalid control character at: line 1 column 40 (char 39)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/create_user.py", line 17, in lambda_handler
    request_body = json.loads(event["body"])
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
```

This is my createuser.py method

```
def __create_user(email_address, password, first_name, last_name):
    print("Using DynamoDB table: " + table_name)

    last_login = int(round(time.time() * 1000))
    user_doc = {
        'user_id': str(uuid.uuid4().hex),
        'email_address': email_address,
        'first_name': first_name,
        'last_name': last_name,
        'password': str(__encrypt_password(password)),
        'last_login': last_login,
        'fav_courses': []
    }

    print("Will write " + str(user_doc))

    try:
        table.put_item(Item=user_doc)

    except:
        print("Failed to write user to Dynamo")
        traceback.print_exc()

    return user_doc
```

My lambdahandler.py

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    request_body = json.loads(event["body"])

    email_address = request_body["email_address"]
    first_name = request_body["first_name"]
    last_name = request_body["last_name"]
    password = request_body["password"]

    new_user = __create_user(email_address, password, first_name, last_name)

    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps(
            {
                "You've asked me to create a new user with": new_user,
            }
        ),
    }
```

I am trying to figure out what is wrong. This is my request

```
    { "emailaddress" : "acjebba@rambler.ru,
      "first name" : "Aca",
      "last name" : "Ljubascikic",
      "password" : "bbbachsahuga_96"
      }
```

Comment: Well you seem to be missing a double quote character in what you posted as ytour request's body, after 'acjebba@rambler.ru'

Comment: @Gaboik1 Thanks, I missed that.